# How to load image from default skin if image does not exist in custom skin?

Tags: magento-1.9, design, theme-fallback, skin

I have a custom skin

```
/skin/frontend/venedor/myskin/
```

this skin has a default folder:

```
/skin/frontend/venedor/default/
```

I have a css file `/skin/frontend/venedor/myskin/css/stlye.css` where an image is loaded:

```
.test { background-image: url(../images/test.png); }
```

How can I load the fallback image in the default theme (/skin/frontend/venedor/default/) if the image can't be loaded? Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

That is Magento default functionlity.

When you specify any images path it to following things.

1. Magento Look into the current theme, If images found then ok otherwise,
2. Magento to look into the default theme/Parent theme.

Comment: Then why does it not work? What is my mistake?

Comment: what code you hace done and where?

Comment: The code is in my question

Comment: Have you check permission of images?

Comment: Yes, permissions are ok

Comment: It seems like magento does has not offer a fallback in this case. So I have to put all my images in both themes...